# Bad type on operand stack in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have the following piece of code:

```
    fun getPriceVariants(request: PriceVariantsRequest): List<PriceVariant> {
        val calculateVariables = Option.Some(request) map { mapPVRequestToPRVariables(it) }

        InstallmentType.values()
                .asSequence()
                .map { installmentType  -> addInstallmentTypeToPRVariables(installmentType, calculateVariables) }

return listOf()
}
```

and `Option` class which is a Functor:

```
sealed class Option<out T> {
object None : Option<Nothing>()
data class Some<out T>(val value: T) : Option<T>()

inline infix fun <R> map(f: (T) -> R): Option<R> = when (this) {
    is None -> this
    is Some -> Some(f(value))
}
```

}

and the function `addInstallmentTypeToPRVariables`:

```
fun addInstallmentTypeToPRVariables(
        installmentType: InstallmentType,
        prVariables: Option<PriceRequestVariables>
): Option<PriceRequestVariables> =
        prVariables map { prVar -> prVar withInstallmentType { installmentType } }
```

When I want to run this code into a test, I receive:

```
    java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    ro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/service/ProductSalePriceService.getPriceVariants(Lro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/model/PriceVariantsRequest;)Ljava/util/List; @83: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Object' (current frame, stack[4]) is not assignable to 'ro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/service/Option'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @83
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'ro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/service/ProductSalePriceService', 'ro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/model/PriceVariantsRequest', 'java/lang/Object', 'ro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/service/Option$Some', integer, 'ro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/service/Option$Some' }
    stack: { 'kotlin/sequences/Sequence', uninitialized 77, uninitialized 77, 'ro/orange/eshop/personalisationengineapiimpl/domain/service/ProductSalePriceService', 'java/lang/Object' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2b12 0bb8 0011 bb00 1359 2bb7 0017 4e03
    0x0000010: 3604 2d3a 0519 05c1 0019 9900 072d a700
    0x0000020: 272d b600 1dc0 001f 3a06 0336 072a 1906
    0x0000030: b600 233a 0a19 0a3a 0bbb 0013 5919 0bb7
    0x0000040: 0017 c000 2500 4db8 002b b800 31bb 0033
    0x0000050: 592a 2cb7 0036 c000 38b8 003e 5703 3eb8
    0x0000060: 0044 b0                                
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@33,{Object[#2],Object[#31],Top,Object[#19],Integer,Object[#19]},{})
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@69,Object[#4])
```

Any ideas about this?

Comment: Could you add the version of the JDK, Kotlin, and any extensions  you are using. A `VerifyError` is quite a bad thing, so this could be a incompatibility or a compiler bug.

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.8.0_192, Kotlin 1.3.41 and Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: I would recommend using the lastest and greatest Kotlin (1.3.50) and if that doesn't work, report a bug http://kotl.in/issue .

Comment: I've switched to latest version of Kotlin, but still facing the issue.

Comment: A solution of mine is to create the subclass instead.